# How to increases optimize SQL query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

I have a action for login user but I need `UserInfo` & `UserPostAccess`.

How to get both with best way and higher optimize and performance?

I try write this code, using a temp table - is there another way?

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, Code, Name, PostId
INTO #User
FROM Users
WHERE UseName = 'myUser' AND Password = 'myPassword'

SELECT * FROM #User

SELECT PermetionId
FROM UserPostAccess
WHERE Id = (SELECT TOP (1) PostId FROM #User)
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, Code, Name, PostId
FROM Users
WHERE UseName = 'myUser' AND Password = 'myPassword'

SELECT * FROM #User

SELECT PermetionId
FROM UserPostAccess
WHERE Id = (SELECT TOP (1) PostId FROM Users 
            WHERE UseName = 'myUser' AND Password = 'myPassword')
```

Answer (score 0):

you get all data together like below

```
SELECT U.*, P.PermetionId
INTO #User
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
  TOP 1 U.id, U.Code, U.Name, U.PostId
 FROM Users 
 WHERE UseName = 'myUser' AND Password = 'myPassword'

)U
LEFT JOIN UserPostAccess P 
ON P.ID=U.PostId

SELECT * FROM #User
```

Comment: A `TOP` with no `ORDER BY` is a sign of a flaw; this'll result in arbitrary rows being returned, which could easily result in inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: I had this option, but I wasn't sure about performance, which one was better or performance ?

Comment: @ZanyarJ.Ahmed Why do you need a top 1? Are there multiple records for same username and password in Users table? That should not be.

Comment: I looking for a specific user account Unique userName already return one row but add TOP 1 for increases performance.

Comment: @ZanyarJ.Ahmed TOP 1 will not give increased performance in such a case

Comment: If you want to increase performance of the JOIN. I suggest you create following  2 indexes - one index on UserPostAccess on ID column which includes PermetionId and another on Users on ID column.

Answer (score 0):

If your query already returns only one record, no need to pull into a #temp table, just do the query and JOIN to the post access directly

```
SELECT TOP 1 
      u.id, 
      u.Code, 
      u.Name, 
      u.PostId,
      pa.PermetionId
   FROM 
      Users u
         JOIN UserPostAccess pa
            on u.PostId = pa.id
   WHERE 
          u.UseName = 'myUser' 
      AND u.Password = 'myPassword'
```

Comment: I had this option, but I wasn't sure about performance, which one was better or performance ?

Comment: @ZanyarJ.Ahmed -- temp table is going to be slower

Comment: @ZanyarJ.Ahmed,  Doing this with the single query.  Since you are looking for a specific user account, it should only ever return a single record only.  But if there are multiple entries in the UserPostAccess for the person, it will just return the first unless you put in some additional qualifier for what the Permetion is most important.

Comment: I have multi  permeation for each UserPost, must remove `TOP 1`

Comment: @ZanyarJ.Ahmed, then I would just leave it to query the user directly, and once logged in, THEN get the Permeation table records to see what access needs to be applied.  If they fail at the login to begin with, who cares what Permeations are available.